# field with memo datatype in a recordset

Tags: ms-access, vba

Is there any specific number of characters in string while use it in where clause?

```
SQL2 = "SELECT DISTINCT " & a & " AS MyString," & b & " FROM tempExtractedtbl"
Set rsGenerate = CurrentDb().OpenRecordset(SQL2)
Do While Not rsGenerate.EOF
    SQL3 = "Select intId from IPDMst where TXTliteral='" & 
    rsGenerate.Fields("MyString").Value & "'"

    Set temprsGenerate = CurrentDb().OpenRecordset(SQL3)
```

Here value of MyString in tempExtractedtbl is:

```
PO_EDGE_00503|Device Charge_1|Device 
Type~Smartphone~Manufacturer~Apple~Model~iPhone 6~Capacity~32 
GB~Colour~Space Grey~Blue Tick~FALSE~4GX~TRUE~Splash Proof~FALSE~Removable 
Battery~FALSE~Expandable Memory~FALSE~HD Video 
Recording~TRUE~NFC~TRUE~Featured~FALSE~Bonus Gift~FALSE~Operating 
System~ios~Hot Buy~FALSE~Root Offering~Mobility Offer~
```

But when its stored in recordset, the value of MyString is trimmed to 255 characters. When i execute

```
?rsGenerate.Fields("MyString").Value
```

in immediate window, I get MyString as

```
PO_EDGE_00503|Device Charge_1|Device 
Type~Smartphone~Manufacturer~Apple~Model~iPhone 6~Capacity~32 
GB~Colour~Space Grey~Blue Tick~FALSE~4GX~TRUE~Splash Proof~FALSE~Removable 
Battery~FALSE~Expandable Memory~FALSE~HD Video 
Recording~TRUE~NFC~TRUE~Featured~F
```

And when I execute SQL3 I get following errors as MyString is trimmed.

[image: Error Description]

Is there any limitation of recordset for memo field as MyString is a field having memo datatype. Is there a way out to store string having length more than 255 characters in a recordset and use it?

Comment: ...and the errors would be? (add them to the bottom of the question)

Comment: I can't replicate this. A where statement, when you're storing it in the queries SQL, is limited by the total amount of characters allowed in an SQL statement, 65536 characters. If you're referring to a table, I think you can go up to a string of 1GB, but I haven't tried if those work in WHERE statements.

Answer (score 2):

`DISTINCT` and Memo fields don't go together.

http://allenbrowne.com/ser-63.html

> Access truncates the memo if you ask it to process the data based on the memo: aggregating, de-duplicating, formatting, and so on.

**Uniqueness**: Since you asked the query to return only distinct values, Access must compare the memo field against all other records. The comparison causes truncation.

Remove DISTINCT from the SELECT SQL.
You may need to create another query that selects the distinct values without the memo, and then use it as the source for another query that retrieves the memo without de-duplicating.

Comment: Hi Andre, thanks for the answer. I've removed distinct from SQL2, but I'm getting same error.

Comment: Please show the final content of `SQL2` before you open the recordset. (Edit your question and add it there) @YashR.

Comment: Hi Andre, when I removed Distinct from SQL2, I got exact value of  MyString. But when I try to execute   Set temprsGenerate = CurrentDb().OpenRecordset(SQL3) it gives error. Is there any limitation of recordset when the fields of table is/are memo?

Comment: The value of SQL3 is:                                                                                                      Select intID from IPDMst where TXTliteral='PO_EDGE_00503|Device Charge_1|Device Type~Smartphone~Manufacturer~Apple~Model~iPhone 6~Capacity~32 GB~Colour~Space Grey~Blue Tick~FALSE~4GX~TRUE~Splash Proof~FALSE~Removable Battery~FALSE~Expandable Memory~FALSE~HD Video Recording~TRUE~NFC~TRUE~Featured~FALSE~Bonus Gift~FALSE~Operating System~ios~Hot Buy~FALSE~Root Offering~Mobility Offer~'

Comment: when I copy SQL3 and run it in MS Access in Query Design, it gives error. When I reduce the size of string in where clause to 255 characters, it works. I dont know what I'm missing here.

Comment: What **exact error** do you get when you run SQL3 from the query editor? @YashR.

Comment: Hi Andre. I've updated the question. Please click on the Error Description at the end of the question to view screenshot of the error.

Comment: You didn't mention that the table is linked from SQL Server. -- Try `TXTliteral LIKE '" & ...` instead of `TXTliteral='" & ...` -- Or use a Pass-Through query.

Comment: Hi Andre, I regret I forgot to mention that all tables are linked from SQL Server. I tried using LIKE but I got same error. Is something wrong in using recordset?